# Taxation for US Citizen remote work for Swiss startup

Tags: usa, taxes, us-citizens, working, switzerland

I am a US citizen based in the US.  I have an opportunity to work with a Swiss startup.  I am wondering what my tax obligation is for 1) salary and 2) any equity in the company that fully vests.  Do I pay tax in Switzerland or the US (hopefully not both)?

I understand location of where the work is performed can change taxation  but I don't know the case for Switzerland.  If it helps to know, I will be physically in the US all of 2021 and then between the US and Switzerland in 2022 onward.

The situation gets hazier in relation to equity.  Do I need a work permit or anything else before I can legitimately accrue equity in a Swiss company?

Comment: You generally need a work permit before you can work in a foreign country, regardless of the form of compensation.  If you perform the work in the US, you don't need a work permit because you are a US citizen.  To do any work in Switzerland you need permission to work in  Switzerland.